# output my Cisco 881 config

Tags: cisco, router, ios, configuration

how does one "print" the startup config or running config.

also what is the best way to import config you have stored as a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Starting conf:
 #show startup-config

Running conf:
 #show running-config

If you have it already on the box, it's as easy as:
 #copy (desired-running-config) running-config

Comment: `copy new-config running-config` won't actually replace the running-config - it will actually merge the two configs. If you want to completely replace a running configuration, you *must* copy the new config to startup-config and then reload.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I knew there was something I was leaving out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to create a TFTP server, especially if you are experimenting a lot. You can copy much easier from the router to the server and the other way around. Once you have the TFTP server, you can just:

```
router#copy tftp://new-config running-config
```